# Android changing permissions not killing app process

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

So, what applications used to do when changing permission while you are in app, app gets killed and everything works fine.

But the app im developing now doesn't get killed, it stays alive.

This is the scenario:

I start application, get asked for permissions, i accept them all, now, i put app in the background, and go to settings and disable all permissions, app doesn't get killed, it only reloads the same activity it was in when I put it in background. How can I kill the process when user changes permission?

Comment: "app doesn't get killed" -- what is your evidence of this? What device are you testing on? What permissions are you requesting and revoking? Note that your process will only be killed if the user *revokes* permissions through Settings, not if the user *grants* permissions. And even then, it is only for the permissions shown on the app's screen in Settings, not stuff like `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Im revoking location permission, when I reopen app from backstack, it is still on the same activity, only reloads it, so it doesn't start again, process is not killed by the permission change. Granting permissions work fine.

Comment: What does "only reloads it" mean? If your process was terminated, you would still be on the same activity anyway, as Android will fork a fresh process for you and return the user to the last-viewed activity, when there is an outstanding recent task for your app.

Answer (score 2):

You have to again perform the check permissions in your onResume method for all your Activity's in order to keep track of the Permission granted to your App.

And if you find that the permission is not available either ask again for the permissions or just finish your app with a message describing why you are closing the app.

Comment: That I know, but all other kind of problems came up, I think I will need to handle it the way it is, since there is no other explanation.

Comment: I get the same behaviour as Miljan. Did you ever get a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Whenever you come from background again your Activity's onResume() will be called so you have to add your checkPermission code there and it will resolve your issue.